# Android bottomsheet how to change layout?

Tags: android, layout, bottom-sheet

I have filter button on persistent bottomsheet and I want to show filtered list on same bottomsheet.When user clicks on filter button bottomsheet layout must change.How can I change layout of bottomsheet? I cant find any examples of it.

Comment: https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc Is that u r looking.?

Comment: I want to change bottomsheet content button to list

Comment: You can change the layout. did you check the link?

Comment: I dont mean bottomsheet with custom layout I mean if user clicks on some button on bottomsheet layout how the custom layout change. Like open different page in bottomsheet.

Comment: Replace the fragment in it